# Rails form_tag elements selection based on url params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi I am using a `form_tag` to set a number of url-params in order to customize how a chartkick chart is loaded.

For example:

```
<%= form_tag("/authors/renderChart/#{params[:id]}", method: "get", remote: true) do %>
 <%= label_tag(:sort, "Sort Direction") %>
 <%= radio_button_tag :sort, "asc"%>
 <%= label_tag(:sort_asc, "Ascending") %>
 <%= radio_button_tag :sort, "desc"%>
 <%= label_tag(:sort_desc, "Descending") %>
 <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Now the question is, can I preselect one of these radio buttons based on existing params? Considering there will be a number of things to customize I want the selected options to stay the same between renders so that when somebody wants to e.g. change the number of items displayed the sort direction stays whatever he selected before.

Is there an easy option or do I need to put that into a helper and surround everything with if-statements like `if params[:sort] == "desc" ... radio_button_tag :sort "desc" true`. That seems a bit cumbersome...

Comment: You can simply do `radio_button_tag :sort, "asc", params[:sort] == 'asc'`

Comment: brilliant. If you make it an answer I'll accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation of [`radio_button_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag), the 3rd argument (boolean) is here to weither check it or not:

```
radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
```

---

**In your case**:

```
radio_button_tag :sort, "asc", params[:sort] == 'asc'
```

Comment: thank you so much. I saw the boolean in the doc but didn't make the connection that I can evauluate this with the params == '' code you gave me :)